# what should I do to analyze the log file

Tags: mongodb, node.js, logging, analysis

I have an app (node.js) running on multiple servers.  each server has its own log (request log, error log, etc).

The log file contains time, http request, sometimes with userId.

What program I can use to analyze log file?  or if there is any node.js plug-in that can do it?

since logs are on multiple servers, should I combine them first before analyzing?

Or, should I store the error into DB instead? (like mongo)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like http://search.npmjs.org/#/winston might be useful for you, it can send logged data to a database. You shouldn't log stuff as plain text but as JSON objects so that you can easily query the logs in the DB.